# Help with strange, strictly multiplicative, model definition

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to understand a model, and I feel a bit stuck and I think I am missing something easy and fundamental. The model in question is rather strange and of the form

$$
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},x_n) = C_0 (1+x_1C_1) (1+x_2 C_2)... (1+x_{n-1}C_{n-1})(1+x_2C_n)
$$

the variables ($x_i$) are mainly categoricals (i.e. one-hot encoded to either 0 or 1), and the coefficients ($C_i$) are then usually small and thus modify the first coefficient ($C_0$, kind of like a base level, since it is $(1+x_iC_i)$).
I cannot remember that I have ever seen such a model and it is very difficult to constrain the coefficients since it is all interactions.

**1. Is there a name for this kind of model?**

**2. Perhaps there is a transformation that I am missing that I can do to make the fitting easier (log(0) is not great though)?**

**3. Are there any recommendations for which model I should replace this with that is easier to constrain (a linear model with interactions included)?**

Technically the model is even stranger and also contain a linear function, like

$$
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},x_n) = A (B + x_1C_1)(1+x_2C_2) (1+x_3 C_3)... (1+x_{n-1}C_{n-1})(1+x_2C_n)
$$

I did not know how to express the coefficients here, but I think it is pretty clear anyway, $A, B,$ and $C_i$ are coefficients, and $x_i$ are variables.

Comment: I don't quite understand your $x_i$. Are these already the 0-1 dummies after the one-hot encoding? If so, your expression is pretty much guaranteed to be zero, because *some* $x_i$ will probably be zero.

Comment: Yes yes, true. If x_i=0 then (x_iC_i) is removed, or (x_iC_i) set to 1. Updated question.

Comment: If you take the log of both sides, and replace $\log(1+x_iC_i)$ with zero or one depending on whether $x_i = 0$ or $1$, you'll get a much simpler model to estimate, and you can easily convert the estimates back to the $C_i$ if it's important to do so.

Comment: @jbowman Right!  But you would likely want to pay attention to heteroscedasticity of the responses.  Expressing the model multiplicatively suggests the conditional values of $f$ are homoscedastic while those of $\log f$ would (therefore) not be.

Comment: @jbowman I am not following this idea completely. 'replace $log(1+x_iC_i)$ with zero or one...' wouldn't that make the whole function just be a sum of 1's (and $log(C_0)$)? $C_i$ is still a coefficient that takes a value determined from a fitting procedure. So $log(1+x_iC_i)$ for $x_i=1$ would be $log(1+C_i)$ which would become something else than 0 (unless the variable is useless for which $C_i=0$).

Comment: You then estimate the coefficients of the individual 0/1 terms, label the terms $x_i^*$ and the coefficients $C^*$, as in  $\log(f(\dots)) = A^* + C_1^*x^*_1 + C_2^*x^*_2 \dots$.